# BackgroundWorker updates UI on RunWorkerCompleted but System hangs due to heavy data load

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, gridview, backgroundworker

I have created a `backgroundWorker` and i am calling `RunWorkerAsync` after `InitializeComponent()` However after googling and through Stack Overflow, I came to know that I cannot update the `UI` through `DoWork` and I need to do this in `RunWorkerCompleted`

So I am doing this but my issue is I am creating a Big datatable in `DoWork` so that I can fill that data in my grid through `RunWorkerCompleted`, but after doing everything when it goes to `RunWorkerCompleted` my application hangs for seconds and then it resumes after loading.

What I feel this is happening because there is lot of data that I am fetching through `DoWork` and when I use `RunWorkerCompleted` to display that data it hangs.

I have approx 50,000 data's that I am fetching from database.

How to resolve this issue. Is there any way apart from  `BackgroundWorker` maybe that I can use and do this stuff. Or maybe through `BackgroundWorker` only I can do some tuneups and it work well.

Comment: Why can't you update the UI from `DoWork`?

Comment: @programmer93 Is that possible. As i did that and it was saying `Illegal cross-thread operation: Control 'myTextBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` I surfed and came to know that UI update is not allowed from `DoWork`

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely update the UI from inside the `DoWork` method. The error that you said you're getting in the comments section is because only the thread that owns a control is allowed to modify it. Other threads however, can make a modification as well but they need to wrap it in a delegate which makes the operation thread-safe. In your `DoWork` method, whenever you want to update a control, follow this procedure:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
  {
     // Update the UI here. For example:
     // myTextBox.Text = "Hello World!";
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe this would still block the UI thread. Maybe if he added the data in smaller chunks it would be less noticeable. I would probably just limit the number of records to a more manageable number, though.

Comment: Well yes adding small blocks of data is the key. I don't know what the data type he's using is but blocks of let's say 100 should do the trick. In any case, it's still better than feeding the UI all the data at once when the worker is done.

Comment: @Ginosaji This should not block .  Invoke is going to make sure you use the thread that owns the controls window handle

Comment: I'm using it in my backgroundworker Dowork function and it still freezes.. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this thread is old, but I had a similar problem and found a different solution not requiring explicit calls to `Invoke`. It is based on the fact that `ProgressChanged` event is there to (pretty much) update the UI by reporting something and kind of indicating that the BG-worker is not frozen or stuck.

Make sure your `BackgroundWorker` has `.WorkerReportsProgress=true` and also add an event handler for `ProgressChanged` event.

Now come the magic, when you report progress, it takes a percentage as `int` (along with an optional `UserState` parameter of type `object`), but does not check the value to be in any particular range. So when I report progress as percentage from `0` to `100`, the progress updates (e.g. 24% complete), but when I send a number outside of that range, something else "*updates*":

My `DoWork` method:

```
...
this._BG_Worker.ReportProgress(-1);
this._BG_Worker.ReportProgress(-2, "Reading NAND");
...
this._BG_Worker.ReportProgress((int)(100.0 * a / b), string.Format("{0}/{1} bytes", a, b));
...
```

My `ProgressChanged` event handler:

```
if (e.ProgressPercentage>=0 && e.ProgressPercentage<=100)
    this.tsslMain.Text=string.Format("{0}% done ({1})", e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState);
else switch (e.ProgressPercentage)
{
    case -1:
        this.lbStatus.Items.Clear();
        break;
    case -2:
        if (e.UserState!=null && e.UserState is string)
            this.lbStatus.Items.Add(e.UserState as string);
        break;
    case ...
}
```

So here it is.